# Will my Circular LinkedList work correctly?

Tags: java, list, boolean, nodes, circular-list

So I am currently trying to create a circle linked list (double linked list with each value having a previous, and a next value not equal to null), and I am not sure if I am properly creating it. My goal is to be able to create a LinkedList of values, and then when I iterate through the list, hasNext() should always return true (no null values). I think there is something wrong with the way I am adding values, but I am not sure. Here is the code, with the CircularList class having an inner node class:

```
public class CircularList<E> {
//I decided to still have heads and tails, to link them together
private Node<E> first = null;
private Node<E> last = null;
private Node<E> temp;
private int size;

//inner node class
private static class Node<E>{ //In this case I am using String nodes
    private E data; //matching the example in the book, this is the data of the node
    private Node<E> next; //next value
    private Node<E> prev; //previous value
    //Node constructors, also since in this case this is a circular linked list there should be no null values for previous and next    
    private Node(E data, Node<E> next, Node<E> prev){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
//end of inner node class
public void addValue(E item){
    Node<E> n = new Node<E>(item, first, last);
    if(emptyList() == true){ //if the list is empty
        //only one value in the list
        first = n;
        last = n;
    }
    else{ //if the list has at least one value already
        temp = first;
        first = n;
        first.next = temp;
        last.next = first;
    }
    size++;
}

public boolean emptyList(){
    boolean result = false;
    if(first == null && last == null){ //if there is no values at all
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: So, you think there is a problem, but you're not sure. Why don't you test the code, to make sure?

Comment: If there are compiler errors, then you can be absolutely sure that something is wrong. And if you want to ask about it, then you should post the exact and complete error message in the question, and tell which line it refers to.

Comment: Nope, this code compiles fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a quick scan but this is the bit where it goes wrong:

```
Node<E> n = new Node<E>(item, first, last);
if(emptyList() == true) {
    //if the list is empty
    //only one value in the list
    first = n;
    last = n;
}
```

The `prev` and `next` item inside node are still null here. You should set those too.

```
else {
    //if the list has at least one value already
    temp = first;
    first = n;
    first.next = temp;
    last.next = first;
}
```

Additionally you're not updating `prev` here.

Also consider using a linked list internally as a backing data structure rather then your own node structure. Then you only have to create the circular iterator.

Comment: I am really confused about how to update everything.

Comment: Use pen and paper. Draw the list with zero, one and two elements. Then draw the connections.